# Astro: Adding GoogleLogin component (react-google-login) gives me an "Invalid hook call" error

Tags: reactjs, astrojs

I'm a rookie on React, me and my project manager forked [Anse](https://github.com/anse-app/anse) project built in Astro

We're getting this error when trying to use the `GoogleLogin` component from the 'react-google-login' module:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
    at resolveDispatcher (react.development.js:1476:13)
    at useState (react.development.js:1507:20)
    at y (google-login.js:1:6357)
```

You can search for `<---` in the code bellow to go to the most important code

This is SettingsSidebar.tsx:

```
// imports...

export default () => {
  const { t } = useI18n()
  const $providerSettingsMap = useStore(providerSettingsMap)
  // bug: someTimes providerSettingsMap() is {}
  const generalSettings = () => {
    return ($providerSettingsMap().general || {}) as unknown as GeneralSettings
  }

  return (
    <div class="h-full flex flex-col bg-sidebar">
      <header class="h-14 fi border-b border-base px-4 text-xs uppercase">
        {t('settings.title')}
      </header>
      <main class="flex-1 overflow-auto">
        <AppGeneralSettings // <--- 
          settingsValue={() => generalSettings()}
          updateSettings={updateGeneralSettings}
        />
      // ... more code
```

This is AppGeneralSettings.tsx:

```
import { For } from 'solid-js'
import { langOptions, localesOptions, styleOptions, toneOptions } from '@/locale'
import { useI18n } from '@/hooks'
import SettingsUIComponent from './SettingsUIComponent'
import type { Accessor } from 'solid-js'
import type { GeneralSettings } from '@/types/app'
import type { SettingsUI } from '@/types/provider'
import GoogleLogin from 'react-google-login'; //module I'm trying to use

// ... more code

<div class="mt-2 flex flex-col">
  <For each={settingsUIList()}>
    {(item) => {
      return (
        <SettingsUIComponent
          settings={item}
          editing={() => true}
          value={() => props.settingsValue()[item.key as keyof GeneralSettings] || item.default || ''}
          setValue={(v) => {
            props.updateSettings({ [item.key]: v })
          }}
        />
      )
    }}
  </For>
  <div>
    <GoogleLogin // <--- I added this component from 'react-google-login' and the error started appearing
          clientId="YOUR_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"
          buttonText="Login with Google"
          onSuccess={(response) => {
              console.log(response);
          }}
          onFailure={(error) => {
              console.log(error);
          }}
      /> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Without adding `GoogleLogin` component everything works fine, any ideas of what can be the reason for the problem? Thank you in advance